# Unable to import the latest version of a package: Google Colab

Tags: keras, package, python-import, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use version 2.2.2 of keras in Google Colab in order to get around a compatibility issue with keras_contrib. I first ran

```
 !pip uninstall keras %to get rid of the existing version
 !pip install keras==2.2.2
```

then

```
 import keras
 print(keras.__version__)
```

this gave the output

```
 2.1.6
```

But, when I run

```
 !pip show keras
```

it shows version 2.2.2 is installed.
In any case, importing keras_contrib generates an error which leads me to believe that the older version (2.1.6) is being used.

Why isn't version 2.2.2 being installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Python are you using?
If you're using Python 3, then you should use the command pip3 to install keras.