# How do make an upgrade to a python package in Google-Colab 'permanent'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I've been working on a notebook for some data science project, but I came across this issue with importing updated packages. I'm making plots using matplotlib. Every time I open the notebook, Google Colab imports version 3.2.2.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__ ## returns 3.2.2
```

Obviously, I tried updating the package using `!pip install matplotlib --upgrade`, and this works fine. After restarting the runtime, I now have the updated version of matplotlib (3.5.1). But whenever the session terminates, I am getting errors again on the plots I use because matplotlib's version is reverted back to 2.2.2. I tried using `!pip3` as suggested in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887336/unable-to-import-the-latest-version-of-a-package-google-colab), but I still get the same problem. How do I permanently upgrade a package in Google Colab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several searches, there seems to be no way to do that by default. As explained from the [FAQs](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) of Google Colaboratory:

> Code is executed in a virtual machine private to your account. Virtual
> machines **are deleted when idle for a while**, and have a maximum
> lifetime enforced by the Colab service.

This [article](https://ayoolafelix.hashnode.dev/how-to-permanently-install-a-module-on-google-colab-ckixqrvs40su044s187y274tc), however, is worth a shot. I'll keep installing for now.